# combining several csv files into one with python not aligned

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have several csv files that I want to merge to one file.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/fantasyfinal/stats')

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sort=False)
combined_csv.to_csv("statsmerger.csv", index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

output:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need `axis=1` parameter in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sort=False, axis=1)
```